# Free open source docbook editor?

Tags: linux, editor

What can be used to edit docbook files on Linux?

Preference would be for an open source, GUI tool, but I'll accept less.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one:  [XMLmind DocBook Editor](http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/docbook_editor.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**[LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/)** is a free, open source, GUI tool that can save to DocBook 5.1 XML ("File → Save As… → DocBook (xml)"). It can also read the DocBook files it generates.

There seems little documentation available, but I found out already that it seems based on proper use of the pre-defined paragraph and character styles:

- Paragraph style "Heading 1" will be rendered as `<sect1><title> … </title></sect1>`.
- Character style "Emphasis" will be rendered as `<emphasis> … </emphasis>`.

### Limitations

While LibreOffice may suffice for basic editing, but this feature is not fully developed. For example, I found the following limitations already:

1. It can load from and save to DocBook `article` documents, but not DocBook `topic` documents.
2. It does not generate `<info>…</info>` elements, and when editing these into the XML source LibreOffice will destroy them when opening them the next time by interpreting these as textual content. Even though `<info>` inside `<article>` is valid DocBook ([see](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.1/article.html)).
3. It does not render literature references with the correct elements in the output.
4. It does not include the bibliography list in the output.

This was just from a quick test, so there are probably many more points like that.